# What's the difference between SQL Server Management Studio and the Express edition?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using Express currently. What extra features do I get with the full edition?

Comment: Microsoft spells it out [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/prodinfo/features/compare-features.mspx)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are no differences in Management Studio. The differences are in the database engine LIMITATIONS! The engine is the same but it will deny you some features.

Import/Export wizard in the express edition can be found at:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe

If you dont have it, dowload it from Microsoft:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65111

You could install the [Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3C856B93-369F-4C6F-9357-C35384179543&displaylang=en) to get the cool toys, like the Import/Export wizard and the reports.

The profiler is not part of Management Studio. It is one more application that comes with the full version of the SQL Server. Even if you have it installed your express edition server engine will refuse to work with it.

Comment: I've noticed actual features missing from the SSMS Express vs. Full in versions prior to 2012 (not sure on 2012).  For instance, the intellisense, which is a mixed blessing.

Comment: Intellisense is only supported by database engines 2008 and higher. You will never see intellisense when connecting to a 2005 or older server.

Comment: FYI, for SSMS 2012 Express, the following are apparently included, as an optional part of the installation: "Reporting Services, Analysis Services, and Integration Services technologies, SQL Server Profiler, Database Tuning Advisor, and SQL Server Utility"

Comment: @LarsH None of those tools are part of SSMS. They are additional and independent tools.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are talking about differences in the client tools and not the database engine, the only differences that I have found so far are the lack of reports and the profiler.  In the full version, on the tree of objects you can right click and select from set of standard reports.  In the Express version, that menu option is missing.
The express version does not install the profiler.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the High-Availability options are missing from the Express Edition. The Express *editions* are great for development purposes. Here's the comparison facts:

http://www.microsoft.com/sql/prodinfo/features/compare-features.mspx

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the wordage, I was using the word Version but really meant Edition, at least as per Microsoft's wordage, which is important, right?

Answer (score 5):

The most annoying thing to me are the Import/Export options.  Even devs need that.

Answer (score 3):

One of the feature which prevents me from using Studio Express is the ability to import and export data via the SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services).  It is hard to be a true DBA with just Studio Express.  From a developer's standpoint, Studio Express would typically be sufficient.