# Can SQL Server Express be used to effectively administrate a SQL Server Standard/Enterprise installation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, administration

We have a number of MS SQL Server 2005 installations (both Standard and Enterprise editions) on our webservers. From time to time I need to administrate them from home. Right now I'm using Remote Desktop to connect to my work machine, but I'd prefer to install SQL Server Management Studio on my home machine so that I can work more efficiently. I don't have a spare license, so I was wondering... if I installed MS SQL Server 2005 Express on my home machine, could I use it to effectively administrate the higher-end installations on our servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this question:
[What's the difference between SQL Server Management Studio and the Express edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117347/whats-the-difference-between-sql-server-management-studio-and-the-express-versi)

Also, if you have any trouble doing anything from Managment Studio Express, there are third-party tools out there that have no trouble connecting to SQL Server.

Personally, I've noticed a few things missing out of the box:

- Import/Export
- Activity Monitor
- Job monitor

However, the question I linked to indicated you may be able to restore most of that for use when you connect to a full sql server edition.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm now, from experimentation that Import/Export do work when connecting to 2005 Standard installation from a 2008 Express management console.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a client tools only install of the standard edition (ie. just SSMS) and don't install the database, agent, etc. then I'm pretty sure you don't need another license and won't be violating the EULA. If you want a full install the SQL Server developer edition is only $49 and comes with everything.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/developer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can create backup schedules and maintenance plans in Management Studio Express.