# Difference between SQL Server Management Studio and Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express, sql-server-2012-datatools

I try to understand the difference between SQL Server Management Studio and SQL Server Management Studio Express

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117347/whats-the-difference-between-sql-server-management-studio-and-the-express-editi

Comment: Management Studio is just a User Interface to work with SQL Server (With Any Version/License  of SQL Server) , Express , Standard , Enterprise , Developers are different Licenses of SQL Server with different feature and Limitations.

Comment: **How to find SQL management studio after installing SQL server 2012 express edition**

Comment: Rolled back to the last version edited by @marc_s because the question text had apparently been vandalized by OP.

Answer (score 1):

The "full" SQL Server **Management Studio** is the **management** GUI (graphical user interface) to work with a SQL Server database and is included in all the paid editions of SQL Server.

For the free SQL Server Express edition, SQL Server **Management Studio Express** can be downloaded for free from the Microsoft web site (or is include, as well, in the "Express with Tools" edition). As far as I know, as of SQL Server 2012, the two versions are essentially the same and don't have any differences in terms of features or capabilities they offer

Comment: **How to find SQL management studio after installing SQL server 2012 express edition**

Comment: [This page here lists ***ALL*** the SQL Server **Express** related bits to download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579). You either need `SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe` (32-bit) or `SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe` (64-bit) depending on your installation of SQL Server **Express** ....

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft makes money from licensed SQL Server - it does not make money from Express. So everything about express is going to be crippled in some way.

SSME (SQL Server Management Express) does not have help and does not support any features SQL Server Express does not support - Reporting Services,SQL Server Agent, Analysis Services etc. If you, or your company, cannot afford a licensed version you are stuck with Express but don't expect a go cart to be as good as a car.

Comment: **How to find SQL management studio after installing SQL server 2012 express edition**

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961 you have to download this and install it.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits: that link goes to the **2005** version - not really up to date ....

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579 and choose only install management studio  see - http://www.jasonstrate.com/2013/05/get-just-the-tools-ssms-download/